# How to check data in multiple sheets in Google Spreadsheet with exclusion of one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am making spreadsheet that will let people compare studies they found and let them know if they already are put into database. I chose Google Spreadsheets because it's something most people in my study group can understand. I've got this formula for single cell to be checking every other sheet in document if there have been put exact name already.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH( B3; INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("'"&$K$1&"'!$a$1:$a$5")&"'!$b$3:$b$42")))>0)
```

where B3 is going to point to cell they are putting data into and

```
INDIRECT"'"&INDIRECT("'"&$K$1&"'!$a$1:$a$5")&"'!$b$3:$b$42")
```

is linking to the area it is supposed to be looked for where I included

```
INDIRECT("'"&$K$1&"'!$a$1:$a$5")
```

which is addressing to list via cellname of sheet where I put names of the rest of sheets so that it basically compare every single input with the rest of inputs and return value on which >0 will be red because it exists and 0 will be green because it does not exist yet.

Problem I encountered is that if I do not exclude sheet that person is currently typing data into it will always return >0 because it will be in cell that person filled at that moment. Is there a possibility to exclude single sheet from equation with changeable pointer? Without or with complete restructuring formula I came up with.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet